# How do you sort the results of a query in Realm-Web in React?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, realm

I found how to sort results in Realm Swift but not in Realm Web.
I have this code:

```
const rests = client.db('peace').collection('problems');
rests.find().sort({points:-1}).then(problems=>  
     this.setState({problems: problems, loading: false})
 }).catch(err => alert(`Failed to load documents: ${err}`));
```

and I get the error `sort is not a function`.
I also tried using `sorted` but got the same result.

I did try sorting the result of the documents on the client side but I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the aggregate function to use instead of the find function. Just add the parameter of sort. -1 is for decreasing and 1 is for increasing.

```
const rests =  client.db('peace').collection('problems');
rests.aggregate([{$sort: {points: -1}}])
.then(problems=> {
    this.setState({problems: problems, loading: false})
 }).catch(err => alert(`Failed to load documents: ${err}`));
```

[MongoDB Aggregate Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/mongodb/#aggregate-documents-in-a-collection)

[Aggregate Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/js/latest/Realm.MongoDBCollection.html#aggregate)